# How can I display only certain characters from a mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a list of upcoming events by pulling data from an event table in mysql. Currently the output looks like this:

Upcoming Events
2011-09-21  School Walkathon
2011-10-06  Open House
2011-10-17  PTA Meeting
2011-11-14  PTA Meeting
2011-09-30  Staff Development Day

However, I would like the date to display only the month and day. Here is my code:

```
              <?php

//---Connect To Database
$hostname="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="urbana116";
$dbname="vcalendar3";

mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) OR DIE ("<html><script language='JavaScript'<alert('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.'),history.go(-1)</script></html>");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

//---Query the database into dataset ($result) stop after the fifth item
$query = 'SELECT event_id, event_title, event_date FROM events WHERE event_date >= CURDATE() ORDER BY category_id != 9, category_id != 7, event_date ASC limit 5';
$result = mysql_query($query);

//---Populate $array from the dataset then display the results (or not)
if ($result) {
while ($array= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<TR><td>".$array[event_date]."</TD><td><a href='/vcalendar/event_view.php?event_id=".$array[event_id]."'>".$array[event_title]."</a></td></tr>";
}
}else{
echo "No results";
}

?>
```

I've tried to select just certain characters from the event_date array like this:

```
echo "<TR><td>".$array[event_date][5]."</TD><td><a href='/vcalendar/event_view.php?event_id=".$array[event_id]."'>".$array[event_title]."</a></td></tr>";
```

but that only displays the 5th character, not characters 5-9...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the substr() PHP function: http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Example:

```
substr($array[event_date],5);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date("m-d",srtotime($array[event_date]);
```

//09-05

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
echo "<TR><td>".substr($array[event_date], 5)."</TD><td><a href='/vcalendar/event_view.php?event_id=".$array[event_id]."'>".$array[event_title]."</a></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should format the date.

use `date('m-d',strtotime($array[event_date]))`

This way, you have the flexibility to display it any way you like (say September 21 instead of 09-21)

Answer (score 0):

For more freedom, you can use this:

```
echo "<tr><td>".date("m-d",strtotime($array['event_date']))."</td> ...
```

Change the `m-d` around to whatever format you want. For example, `F dS` would give something like `September 21st`.